result of division of two number in python is not correct
I have part of code that divide two numbers in python,
22313.6/0.8
i expect that result of this code be a integer number but python return of a float number and this result s wrong. the correct result is 27892.Do you have point about this, why? please guide me for solve on .

Floating point representations are always an approximation. See SO link

There are several questions in that small question, some of them not exactly duplicate.
1. Typing
A division returns a float. However exact and integer the result may be.
In your case, result is not exact (because there is no such thing as an exact 22313.6 in floats, see later). But even if it were. For example
22312.5/1.5

is exact (22313.5 has an exact representation. So has 1.5)
Yet, result is 14875.0 not 14875. This is the float division operator, it returns a float.
Even exact integer division between 2 integers, is a float.
8/2

is 4.0 not 4
At least with python 3, but I assume you are using python 3.
2. //
There is an integer division operator that returns integer result (either exact, or with remainder dropped, if there is any)
8//2

is 4
That operator also works with float arguments. But then returns a float (but a float that is always an integer; I never understood why)
So
22312.5//1.5

is 14875.0
Of course, you can convert it to int
int(22312.5//1.5)

is 14875
(no need for round/floor/ceil, since int, at least if they are not too big, have all an exact float representation, so no risk here to end up with int(14874.9999999999999) being rounded to 14874. At least as long as the result is indeed 14875, that is if arguments of division have an exact float representation.
3. Float representation
That is the part of the question that is a duplicate. See provided link.
But, in short, floats can only represent number that can be written in the form A×2ᴮ, with A and B integers (and even there, there are limits to possible values of A and B, because of size limitation).
1.5 can. It is 3×2⁻¹
22313.5 can. It is 44627×2⁻¹
1.15625 can. It is 37×2⁻⁵
Etc.
One other way to say it: if you keep multiplying a number that has an exact float representation by 2, at one point you end up getting an integer. If you never reach an integer, then your starting number has no exact representation.
22313.6 cannot. No number ending with .6 can. If you multiply it by 2, it will end with .2 (44627.2). Multiply by 2 again, and it ends by .4 (89254.4). Multiply by 2 again, it ends by .8 (178508.8). Multiply by 2 again, and it ends by .6 again (357016.6). Then an endless cycle .2, .4, .8, .6, .2, ... so you'll never reach an integer.
Likewise of course of 0.8 → 1.6 → 3.2 → 6.4 → 12.8 → … whose decimal places belong the the same cycle.
A necessary (but not sufficient) rule is that a number has to be either an integer, or to end with 5 to have a float representation. So if a non-integer doesn't end with 5, you know without any computation that there float representation is not exact.
And if their float representation is not exact, then the division has some error. Sometimes it will end up slightly over the exact value, (33470.4/1.2 = 27892.000000000004), so you have the exact value when you round. Sometimes slightly under (your 22313.6/0.8)
You are in this last case.
Because, in reality, there is no such thing as 22313.6 in float64. The closest exact float64 is
22313.5999999999985448084771633148193359375
(In other words, in float64, 22313.6 is a synonym of 22313.5999999999985448084771633148193359375 ; the former is shorter but inexact, the latter is exact)
Likewise 0.8 is a shorter but inexact writing of exact float64
0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
4. struct
I know that because :
import struct
A = struct.unpack('l', struct.pack('d', 22313.6))[0] & (2**52-1) + 2**52
B = int(math.log2(22313.6)
# 22313.6 ≈ A * 2**B / 2**52
# To know exact value, I can rely on big integer exact arithmetic
A * 2**B * 10**100 // 2**52 is
# 223135999999999985448084771633148193359375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
# Hence, with dot in the right place (100 places from the end) 
# A*2**B/2**52 = 22313.5999999999985448084771633148193359375

struct package allows you to know how (in memory) numbers are stored. What I do here is create the 8 bytes that represent 22313.6 in float64 (double aka 'd'),

thank you very much. i understand your descriction about my problem.

This is a very beginner-friendly question. We're assuming Python3, Python2 did things differently.
In Python, there are two different division operators.

Floating-Point Division (/): Always returns a float value (Not true in Python2).


Example: 
print(10/2)  # 5.0
print(10.2/2)  # 5.1



Integer (Floor) Division (//): Returns integer if both operands are integers. If one operand is a float, then it returns a float value.


Example: 
print(10//2) # 5
print(10.0//2) # 5.0


That's why your answer gives float values:

print(22313.6/0.8) # 27891.999999999996
print(22313.6//0.8) # 27891.0


If you want a whole number as your answer, you can use the 'int' or 'round' functions. 'int' will truncate everything after the decimal point, and round, by default, will round to 0 decimal places.
> print(int(22313.6 / 0.8)) # 27891
> print(round(22313.6 / 0.8)) # 27892


thanks. i want to use Desimal module for divide it numbers and similiar.
